# Change text of a button dynamically in VB.net (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Hi I have button that reads "True", When the user presses it, I want it to read "False". I have tried the following but it does not work. Can someone help please? Thanks

```vb
    Private Sub buttonTrue_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles buttonTrue.Click

buttonTrue.Content = "False"
```

XML for button:

```xml
<Button Content="True" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Margin="185,260,156,0" Name="buttonTrue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not work"?

Comment: When I press the button the default text ("True") still shows

Comment: Can you post some of the XAML from the actual view?  At first glance, what you have looks like it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your **XAML** does not have a `Click` event handler. Add it: `Click="buttonTrue_Click"`

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks to me like it should work.  But the problem I see is that once the button is clicked, it should say false, and will never change after that, as you have no conditions.

There are a couple of other things I would consider, depending on what you're looking for.

One thing would be to look at a ToggleButton if you're looking for it to toggle between True and False.  Bind the content to the state through a converter.

Another would be if you want the button to still appear the same as a regular button instead of a ToggleButton would (with one state showing a white background with black text).  That would be to use a condition statement and again bind the content through a converter.  For instance, set up a bool variable, and have the event change the state of that variable, and use NotifyPropertyChanged to update the UI.